# How to find C# entry point for Non exe program?

Tags: c#, entry-point

All information I read regarding C# entry point class relate to:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
```

As this is specific to an EXE program.

But my program is a C# Automation Test framework (.cs within the solution), designed with Specflow feature files and step definitions.

I have now added an (entry point) class called Program.cs - Int Main class but I’ve noticed that this entry point class is not called any time when running my automation tests. Most likely because my program is not an EXE program but a Test framework.

How can I find the C# entry point for Non exe program?

As I want to use utilise my 'Reporting' code from one class that will be called every time I run a test:

```
namespace Project.Core
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            Adapter.DefaultSearchTimeout = 5000;

            int error;
            try
            {
                error = TestSuiteRunner.Run(typeof (Program), Environment.CommandLine);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                TestReport.Setup(ReportLevel.Debug, "myReport.rxlog", true);
                Report.Screenshot();
                throw new ApplicationException("Error Found", e);
            }
            return error;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not familiar with Specflow, but is it a program that loads and runs your code?  If so, you'll have to check Specflow's documentation for how it decides what classes to load, what methods to run, and in what order.  Most likely, it will instantiate one of your classes and call a non-static method on it, so changing where you place a static Main method probably won't have any effect.

Comment: Try reading [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/82891/BDD-using-SpecFlow-on-ASP-NET-MVC-Application) on SpecFlow.

Answer (score 4):

Non-exe projects (i.e. DLLs) have no entry-point.  They are APIs that are called by other processes, which have their own entry-points.

You should research the appropriate "before test" methodology for the test framework you are using with SpecFlow.  For example in MSTest, such code would go in a method with a signature of:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void TestInitialize()
{
    // Your code
}
```

[MSDN Documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testinitializeattribute%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation on 'Non-exe projects (i.e. DLLs) having no entry-point'. That's been very useful. I am using MsTest but unfortunately [TestInitialize] did not act as a Try/Catch as I was aiming for. As my project is using both MsTest and teh Ranorex API I cannot be sure what aspect of the project is being initialised before/during a test run. So I have decided to add the Try/Catch code structure directly into every method in my project.

Comment: You could try adding one of each of the methods and attributes (`[AssemblyInitialize]`, `[ClassInitialize]`, `[TestInitialize]`, `[TestCleanup]`, `[ClassCleanup]` and `[AssemblyCleanup]` as described in the MSDN Documentation) to your project and step through it in the debugger and see what happens to give you a bit more insight.  You might find over time that having the `try-catch` in every method becomes unmaintainable as the number of tests increases.

Answer (score 0):

As my project is using both MsTest and the Ranorex API I cannot be sure what aspect of the project is being initialised before/during a test run. So I have decided to add the Try/Catch code structure directly into every Step Defintion method in my project.

```
Try()
{
    // code
}
Catch (Exception e)
{
    TestReport.Setup(ReportLevel.Debug, "myReport.rxlog", true);
    Report.Screenshot();
    throw new ApplicationException("Error Found", e);
}
```

And I can easily move the Catch code into a helper class so that I only have one instance of the code being used through my project:

```
catch (Exception)
{
    WpfHelpers.ExtensionMethods.CatchException(null);
}
```

Helper class:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void CatchException(SystemException e)
        {
            TestReport.Setup(ReportLevel.Debug, "myReport.rxlog", true);
            Report.Screenshot();
            throw new ApplicationException("Error Found", e);
        }
}
```

Note that I am using this structure so that I can utilise the Report.Screenshot functionality of Ranorex when a failure occurs.

Comment: I would recommend that you just use `throw` in the `catch` block rather than throwing a new exception so you get all the exception metadata (i.e. type and original stacktrace) in the MSTest results, rather than every failure just being an `ApplicationException` thrown from your test code.

Comment: Good point. I've now tested using both: throw new Exception("Error Found", e); and throw(e);.                                        throw(e); returns a more clearly read Exception Handled stacktrace: **-> error: No element found for path '//nothing' within 1000ms. Test method -Tests.Features.ReportScreenshotFeature.ReportScreenshot threw exception: 
Ranorex.ElementNotFoundException: No element found for path '//nothing' within 1000ms.**

Comment: You should just use `throw` in the original catch instead of `throw e` in `CatchException(Exception)` so the stacktrace is preserved.